# Dell D3818DW: How to connect KVM between PC and Macbook pro mid-2012?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I just bought a Dell 38" Ultrawide (D3818DW) and I wanna get all the cables I need while I wait for it to arrive.
I want to use the KVM feature of this monitor between my MBP mid-2012 and my PC so I can switch seamlessly between them.

I've read that I need a Mini-Display Port to Display Port cable to connect my MBP. And to use the KVM feature, I have to also connect a USB downstream cable to the MBP.

However, I also read that connecting a MBP via USB-C can bypass having to connect a USB Downstream to use the KVM feature. My Mac has a Thunderbolt 2 port and two USB 3.0 ports.

So, can I just use something like the [StarTech TBT3TBTADAP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019FPJDQ2) TB 3 to Legacy TB adapter for display and KVM? So I won't have to have two wires sticking out of my MBP when using the KVM feature.

Comment: I've made an edit to your question - first, there was two distinct questions - the functionality of the monitor and how to connect it.  I removed the question which would be most classified as a "you're expected to have done sufficient research" (this is something Dell should answer for you) and narrowed the scope down to a single topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, can I just use something like...a TB 3 to
>   Legacy TB adapter for display and KVM? So I won't have to have two
>   wires sticking out of my MBP when using the KVM feature.

**No.  This cannot be done.**  Thunderbolt 3 is backward compatible with Thunderbolt 2 and 1.  It cannot make a Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port suddenly Thunderbolt 3.

Thunderbolt is *backward compatible* not forward.

> I also read that connecting a MBP via USB-C can bypass having to
>   connect a USB Downstream to use the KVM feature.

The industry has made [USB-C very confusing](http://So,%20can%20I%20just%20use%20something%20like%20the%20StarTech%20TBT3TBTADAP%20TB%203%20to%20Legacy%20TB%20adapter%20for%20display%20and%20KVM?%20So%20I%20won't%20have%20to%20have%20two%20wires%20sticking%20out%20of%20my%20MBP%20when%20using%20the%20KVM%20feature.). Basically, it's not if you have a USB-C port, it's if your computer supports USB v3.1 which uses a type C connector.  The USB ports on your existing Mac are 2.0, so it will not work as a single cable solution.  You'll need both the DisplayPort and USB downstream cable.

Answer (score 0):

No, that product cannot be used for this purpose as it does not transfer the actual display signal (i.e. what would be called Alternate Mode in USB-C), nor is it for connecting newer TB3/USB-C devices to an older computer - it is actually for connecting old TB/TB2-devices to a new TB3 computer.